# Tengo problema de permisos de acceso en apache

Tags: php, apache, localhost

He instalado lamp en linux mint, y despues he creado un enlace simbólico en /var/www/html" a un directorio en el home, para tenerlo más a mano, pero me dice que no tengo permiso para acceder a él.

En el apache2.conf, en la sección "Directory /var/www/" cambié en AllowOverride "None" por "All":

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Añadí "AccessFileName .htacess" y reiniciado el servicio apache2, pero me sigue dando el error de permisos, ¿hace falta añadir o cambiar algo más?
######################################################################

Pues al final estuve dandole mil vueltas, porque no funcionaba nada, cambiando el propietario de los directorios, cambiando configuraciones del apache... y no funcionaba nada, siempre me daba acceso prohibido.

Fui mirando cada uno de los directorios, mirando cómo tenian los permisos, hasta que vi que el directorio del usuario dentro del home

`/home/usuario/`

tenía desactivado los permisos de lectura a terceros usuarios, así que se los di y ya funciona sin prolemas.

Comment: El usuario de apache debe tener permiso de lectura sobre tu directorio en home. ¿Con qué usuario creaste el enlace simbólico?

Comment: Pues el enlace lo cree utilizando sudo, así que el propietario es root

Answer (score 0):

El usuario que debe tener acceso al directorio es www-data, el cual pertenece al grupo www-data. Debes hacer:

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data /ruta/a/tu/directorio -R
```

Answer (score 0):

Instale Linux Mint 21.2, apache2 y php 7.4. y trabajo con enlaces simbólicos desde mi usuario linux y creo un enlace simbolico a /var/www/html para poder trabajar mas comodo con apache netbeans.

Gracias ese era el detalle de los permisos de la carpeta.

**/home/usuario/**

**tenía desactivado los permisos de lectura a terceros usuarios**

Comment: No añadas “gracias” como respuesta. Cuando tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), podrás [votar a favor de preguntas y respuestas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) que encuentres útiles. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/397072)